# Android - Missing Google Play Services in VERSION: 2.1.1.0?

Tags: android, sdk, google-play-services

It is very strange, I am very new and as per setup instructions, I need to install  Google Play services from SDK Manager, I tried a lot and finally gave up. 
I just downloaded the latest VERSION: 2.1.1.0 of SDK from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

See below. [image]

Can you please help me how to install the Google Play services ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Repository is all you need for Google Play Services and you have that installed.

Comment: Thanks, is this some change in the latest version ? Also, I am following setup guide and it says I need to create SDK for API 19, I only see 23 in the latest.  It is really confusing...

Comment: @Kumar - what exact setup guide are you following?

Comment: I am following step 7 at : https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide_hat/frameset.htm?aa4ede549b4b4a508a9d294995707aee.html

Comment: Well, Cordova is on version 6.2 already, so it certainly is not an up to date guide. There is the Obsolete checkbox at the bottom right which should allow you to install API 19 items as well.

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove the cache option, and select https and obsolete option to have all of it to work.